# $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of a parametric curve

Tags: algebraic-curves, parametric

Given $x = sin^2(t)$, $y = cos^2(t)$, I need to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in every non-singular point of the curve.

So $\frac{dy}{dt} = -2sin(t)cos(t)$ and $\frac{dx}{dt} = sin(2t)$.

To find the singularity points -

$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt} = 0\iff sin(2t)=sin(t)=0 \iff t=k\pi$

So for every $t \not=k\pi$, $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-2sin(t)cos(t)}{sin(2t)}=\frac{-sin(2t)}{sin(2t)}=-1$

Am I correct so far? is it true that the linear equation for this curve is $y=1-x$?

Thanks

Comment: oops, $-2sin(t)cos(t) = -sin(2t)$

Comment: Hint: What do you know about $\sin^2t+\cos^2t$? (Also, please use `\sin` and `\cos` in LaTeX. And I think you wanted to use $t$ for your parameter in the opening.)

Comment: ...and what is $\,t\,$, anyway??

Comment: $cos^2(t) = 1- sin^2(t) = 1-x$